# How to set the type of array with dataset in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have a source data like this:

```
{A:123,B:"Hello world",C:[{D:123,E:"Spark"}]}
```

And i have a Object:

```
case class TestClass (A:Int;B:String;C:???)
val obj:Dataset[TestClass] = df.as[TestClass]
```

How should I define the type of C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option

```
case class Nested(D: Long, E: String)
case class TestClass (A: Long, B:String, C: Seq[Nested])
```

Usage:

```
spark.read.json(sc.parallelize(
  Seq("""{"A": 123, "B": "Hello world", "C": [{"D": 123, "E": "Spark"}]}"""
))).as[TestClass].show

+---+-----------+-------------+
|  A|          B|            C|
+---+-----------+-------------+
|123|Hello world|[[123,Spark]]|
+---+-----------+-------------+
```